# Simple JNDI lookup from JDK 11 client to Weblogic 10.3.6 (JDK 7) server not working

Tags: jndi, corba, weblogic11g, java-11

**Server Environment: Weblogic 10.3.6, JDK 1.7**

I have a simple working Java SE client application runing with **JDK 7**. In client I am doing very simple JNDI look of a resource hosted server mentioned above.

**Jars in ClassPath:** wlthint3client.jar

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Hashtable t = new Hashtable();
    t.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    t.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7003/");
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(t);

    String jndiName = "weblogic.jdbc.DataSource.Workflow";

    Object obj = ic.lookup(jndiName);
    System.out.println("Found it");
}
```

I have to **upgrade** my working Java SE client application from **JDK 7 to JDK 11**. The server environment remains same.

As soon as I upgrade client to JDK 11, I hit following error. Which is expected because corba jars have been moved out from JDK 11.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/SystemException
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.<clinit>(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:202)
    at weblogic.jndi.spi.EnvironmentManager$DefaultFactoryMaker.<clinit>(EnvironmentManager.java:27)
    at weblogic.jndi.spi.EnvironmentManager.getInstance(EnvironmentManager.java:49)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at com.test.JndiLookupTestJdk11.main(JndiLookupTestJdk11.java:16)
```

Added **jacorb-omgapi-3.8.jar** to client classpath to fix above exception.

After this I am hitting following timeout exception and not giving any clue. Server is up and running because my old client is working.

Error is at this line

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(t);
```

**Stacktrace**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream (file:/C:/Users/ke64/OneDrive%20-%20Sun%20Life%20Financial/work_eclipse-jee-2018-12-R/jndi-lookup-test-jdk11/lib/wlthint3client.jar) to method java.io.ObjectInputStream.clear()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:7003: Bootstrap to: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7003' over: 't3' got an error or timed out]
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:40)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:792)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:368)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at com.test.JndiLookupTestJdk11.main(JndiLookupTestJdk11.java:16)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:7003: Bootstrap to: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7003' over: 't3' got an error or timed out
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:216)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:165)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:353)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Bootstrap to: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7003' over: 't3' got an error or timed out
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:365)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:260)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteCluster(RJVMFinder.java:316)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:205)
    ... 11 more
```

**Questions**

1. Has anyone got it working with configuration? Any idea
   how to fix this? Do I need to add any specific version of corba jars?
2. I am thinking that standard J2EE feature of JNDI lookup should work. Is Weblogic 10.3.6 not compatible with JDK 11 client?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding to an old question .. I had to look into a similar scenario recently. Just adding my findings here. Real credit should go to [stephen-felts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4095026/stephen-felts) as his reply gave me the idea to try this out.

Looked at a Spring Boot client on OpenJDK 11 attempting to talk to JMS queues on WebLogic 10.3.6.0 on Oracle JDK 6.

Trying to use the wlthint3client.jar from 10.3.6 wasn't of much help because of the CORBA dependencies. Following [this SAS post](https://support.sas.com/kb/63/716.html) for dependencies to add for JDK 11. Could make the ClassNotFound errors go away by adding dependencies `org.glassfish.corba:glassfish-corba-org:4.2.4` `org.glassfish.pfl: pfl-tf:4.1.2` but still kept seeing the `'t3' got an error or timed out` exception message as the OP.

Seeing `WLS 14.1.1` is certified for JDK 11, installed that and copied out the bundled wlthint3client.jar from the `<WLS_SERVER>/lib` folder and configured the SpringBoot client to use it. Could successfully post messages to the queue.

I couldn't find any official confirmation on the Oracle website though, so I don't know if this approach is good enough to use in a production environment.

Answer (score 6):

There is no shipping version of WebLogic Server that works on JDK 11.
WLS 10.3.6 isn't even close (it doesn't even work on JDK 8).

The closest shipping version is WLS 12.2.1.3.0, which was pretty much working on JDK9 but has been broken with subsequent changes in JDK 10 and JDK 11.

A version of WebLogic Server that is certified on JDK 11 is planned for the second half of 2019.

Comment: Thank Stephen.. It really helps me make decision to move forward.

Comment: Do we know if there is a supported version for Jdk 11? I tried searching for one, couldn't find.

Comment: WLS 14.1.1.0.0 that was available at the end of March 2020 supports JDK8 and JDK11.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same Problem whilst using jdk11 and wlthint3client 10.3.6.0.181016 and trying to connect to weblogic with t3.
Solution was to use the glassfish-dependencies mentioned above (but there is a typo, must be -orb in artId; see below for the correct ones) and using Version 12.2.1.3.180717 of wlthint3client. Here's the Set:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlthint3client</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.1.3.180717</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.corba</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-corba-orb</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.pfl</groupId>
    <artifactId>pfl-tf</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```